# React Native boderStyle styling not working

Tags: react-native

**React Native version: 0.60**

I am trying to give dotted border to a view but it give me a warning and doesn't show the dotted border.

```
borderstyle: 'dotted'
```

Comment: what's the warning? are you using `borderStyle:"dotted"`

Comment: You need to edit your question and provide us the code you've tried and the warning, otherwise we can't really help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to give a border width  first to have a border of dotted .

```
style = {{ 
    borderColor: 'red',
    borderStyle: 'dotted',
    borderWidth: 2
}}
```

Comment: Can you post an expo snack link for the same?

Comment: this one works but can it be possible for only top border

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a style for dotted border and then apply to the View component in your render.

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  dottedBorder: {
    borderColor: "black",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderStyle: "dotted"
  });
  
  <View style={styles.dottedBorder}>
```